# How to run XCTest over Wifi using XCode 9 and iOS 11

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, xcode9-beta

I am using following environment:
Xcode version 9 beta
iOS 11
iphone 7

I am able to run/debug applications on my iPhone over wifi network. debug over wifi feature is working flawlessly. However, when I try to run my test cases, iOS is unable to run them.

iOS is throwing following error:

> {Error Domain=XCTMobileDeviceFramework Code=127
>   "kAMDNoWifiSyncSupportError: Device doesn’t support wireless sync."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=kAMDNoWifiSyncSupportError: Device
>   doesn’t support wireless sync.}}}

I have used iTunes and enable device sync over wifi option. Still I am facing same issue.

Is it possible to run test cases on my iPhone device using xcode 9 new feature "debug over wifi"?

Answer (score 0):

It is problem with xcode 9 beta 1. I took xcode 9 beta 2 today and its working fine.

Basically this feature is not included in xcode 9 beta 1.